# Split a field for a aggregates

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an field with a variety of (multi word) category tags that I'm trying to figure out how to get aggregates for.  For any given document there may be one or more tags separated by `|` characters.

I have the following mapping for my field:

```
"category": {
    "type": "keyword",
    "fields": {
      "raw" : {
        "type": "keyword",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      }
    }
}
```

This works for storing the data, but when I try to get the aggregates, for example:

```
{"aggregates": {
    "categories": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "category"
        }
    }
}}
```

It returns whatever the field contains.  For example, if I have two documents with categories of

- `Facilities|Information Technology`
- `Human Resources|Information Technology`

I'd like to get back something like:

- `Information Technology: 2`
- `Facilities: 1`
- `Human Resources: 1`

Any suggestions on what I need to do to either split the data as part of my mapping or aggregates query?

Comment: If you are certain the values will be separated by the pipe symbol, you could specify a custom analyzer with a pattern tokenizer that splits on | and use tremvectors API to get this info.